# How do I create a descriptor wallet?

Tags: wallet, output-script-descriptors

Using Bitcoin Core from today (almost 0.21):

I ran `./configure`. It said `with sqlite = yes`. `ldd $(which bitcoind)` shows it is linked to `libsqlite3.so`.

Now, I started a signet node using `bitcoind -signet`. It has synced.

Now I want to create a descriptor wallet. So I tried looking in the `man bitcoin-wallet`, but it doesn't mention it.

I tried `bitcoin-cli help` and it lists:

```
createwallet "wallet_name" ( disable_private_keys blank "passphrase" avoid_reuse descriptors load_on_startup )
```

I tried:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -signet createwallet default_wallet -descriptors 
error: Error parsing JSON: -descriptors
$ bitcoin-cli -signet -descriptors createwallet default_wallet
Error parsing command line arguments: Invalid parameter -descriptors
```

How do I create a descriptor wallet?

Comment: `descriptors` is not a command-line option to `bitcoin-cli`, it's a boolean argument to the "createwallet" RPC. It should be "true" or "false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`descriptors` is a boolean argument, so it should either be `true` or `false`. As with all RPCs, the argument is positional by default. So your command would look like

```
bitcoin-cli -signet createwallet "mywallet" false false "" false true
```

You can specify that the arguments be named so you don't have to put the position correctly. In that case, you do

```
bitcoin-cli -signet -named createwallet wallet_name="mywallet" descriptors=true
```

Comment: why is `-named` necessary if passing `wallet_name=...`?

Comment: So that bitcoin-cli knows to interpret that as `<argname>=<arg>` instead of a single argument. Then it can pass everything into bitcoind correctly.